# Is it okay to represent a point as (P_1, P_2, P_3) or do I have to use a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

I am trying to write a simple explanation of the point-direction form of a line.

$\mathbf{l} = \mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{v}$

but using an actual point instead of a vector seems like a more natural way of thinking about it.

$\mathbf{l} = P+t\mathbf{v}$

but I also want to do the coordinate form of a line, which would look like:

$x=P_1+tv_1$

$y=P_2+tv_2$

$z=P_3+tv_3$

and now I'm in this silly situation of worrying about if I can write it out in the way that makes the most sense without being wrong. So can I do it like that or do I have to do it as a vector?

Comment: The $v_i$ shouldn't be bold.

Comment: The equation $\mathbf{l}(t) = \mathbf{a} + t\mathbf{v}$ with $\mathbf{a} = (P_1, P_2, P_3)$ means exactly the same as your proposed representation. Two vectors are the same if their coordinates are the same, which in this case is $\mathbf{l}(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$ and $\mathbf{a} + t\mathbf{v} = (P_1 + tv_1, P_2 + tv_2, P_3 + tv_3)$.

Comment: so I am allowed to use the point when doing coordinate form? e.g. x=P_1+tv_1. I am confused because In my head I always think of position vectors as points but now that I am writing it out I'm not sure if I can do that little cheat. For example, you can't do vector addition and scalar multiplication with a point, only a vector, right? Or can you? ..i mean technically.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to do that, but I suspect you are misunderstanding a very vital fact about vectors. In a way the point $P = (P_1, P_2, P_3)$ and the **vector** $\mathbf{a}  = (P_1, P_2, P_3)$ are exactly the same for your purpose. It doesn't make sense to say $P + t\mathbf{v}$ because the point $P$ doesn't have the additional structure of a vector, so adding it to the vector $t\mathbf{v}$ is not defined.

Comment: In response to your recent edit, you need to understand this about a vector space: the scalar multiplication is not an operator for multiplying vectors and points, it's an operation multiplying vectors and scalars. In this case, your scalars seem to be the set of real numbers, not points.

Comment: okay, i get it. vectors are a superclass and points don't have those methods, so to speak. that's kind of what i was worried about. and in my example of x=P_1+tv_1 i'm just kind of lucking out. That's really unfortunate though. Don't you think it's easier to understand it with a point than a vector?

Comment: I think it makes sense conceptually to add a displacement vector to a point in order to obtain a new point. The wikipedia article on [affine spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) mentions that: "Thus it makes sense to subtract two points of the space, giving a translation vector, but it does not make sense to add two points of the space. Likewise, it makes sense to add a displacement vector to a point of an affine space, resulting in a new point translated from the starting point by that vector."

Comment: The bottom line is that in $\mathbb R^n$, you can largely gloss over the technical differences between points and vectors and use them pretty much interchangeably.